# How do you call this fact about sum of powers of n-th unity root?

Tags: summation, power-series, roots-of-unity

I often see identity

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{\tau ika/n} = \cases {n \quad \text{ if }n | a\\0\quad \text{ otherwise}}$$

in the context of generating functions. It allows to zero out all members of sequence, indexed by $a$, except every $n$-th one (n divides a). The textbooks seem to consider it `so obvious that it does not need any proof`. Is it right or there is one?

Comment: Such exponential sums arise in the context of the discrete Fourier transform, and can be seen as a consequence of Viete's theorem applied to $x^n-1$ or to a cyclotomic polynomial.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Can you put that slowly as answer? As you can see, I am not advanced mathematician to understand the hints.

Comment: This an related facts often go by the name "orthogonality relations."

Comment: @quid I thought that orthogonality stands for the product of two functions, e.g. $e^{ax}\cdot e^{bx}$. Do you mean that we have a kind of dot-product here?

Comment: In a certain sense yes. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_table You are delaing with the case for a cyclic group of order $n$.

Answer (score 3):

(Assuming that $\tau$ in your formula stands
for $2 \pi$) this is an immediate consequence
of the ["well-known" formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series)
for the (finite) geometric sum
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k = \cases {n \quad \quad \text{ if } x = 1\\ \frac{x^n-1}{x-1}\quad \text{ otherwise}}
$$
applied to $x = e^{\tau ia/n}$. (Note that $x = 1$ exactly if $n$ divides $a$.)

Comment: Yes, Tau stands for 2π, read http://www.tauday.com/tau-manifesto. I am fond it love with it.

Answer (score 1):

The intuitive geometric approach is to look at all the $n$th roots. I mean, draw them as points on a piece of paper (or in your head). See how nicely they're distributed, all evenly along the unit circle. That means their sum is equal to $0$.

Now raise them to some power. If that power is a multiple of $n$, then they will all end up at $1$, and their sum will be $n$. However, if the power is not a multiple of $n$, they will still be spread out. They might end up some on top of others, in which case you will have "piles" of points, where each pile has $\gcd(n, a)$ points. So each pile will weigh the same as any other pile, and they're still evenly spread out along the unit circle (although possibly a bit sparser). Therefore their sum is $0$.

Comment: Oh, I just gave the same answer as yours. This is the real answer. I hope you don't mind if I also keep mine.+1

Comment: when you meet Gauss sums this argument is useful.

Comment: I think I have got what you wanted to say with help of [this answer](http://qr.ae/3KRD5) (I have discovered the same question as mine in quora). It says that first ring (a=1) adds up to 0 both due to simmetry and it is easy to check with geometric progression formula. Then, every multiplication with primary root will rotate the zero but this should not increase the amplitude.

Answer (score 0):

The sum becomes zero when multiplied by $\exp(\tau\mathbf ia/n)-1$, which factor is nonzero when $n\not\,\mathrel\backslash a$, so the sum must have been $0$ already in this case. But when $n\mathrel\backslash a$ then $\exp(\tau\mathbf ika/n)=1^k=1$ and the sum becomes $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}1=n$.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers $x_k =e^{2\pi i \frac{k}{n}}$, $0 \le k \le n-1$ are the roots of the polynomial $x^n-1$.
The sums $S_a= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x_k^a$ have period $n$ in $a$ ( $S_{a+n} = S_a$ ) so it is enough to prove the assertion for $0\le a \le n-1$. For $a=0$ it's true (easy check). Let's show that $S_1, \ldots, S_{n-1} =0$. We can show in fact that for every  symmetric polynomial in $x_k$ homogenous of degree $d$, $1\le d \le n-1$ we have $P(x_1, \ldots, x_n) =0$. Indeed, $P(x_1,\ldots, x_k)$ will be expressed in terms of the fundamental symmetric polynomials in $x_k$,
$e_1 = \sum x_k$, $e_2 = \sum x_k x_l$, $e_n = x_1 \ldots x_n$. Now from Viete relations we have $e_1 = ...= e_{n-1} = 0$. Now any monomial in the expression of  $P(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ in terms of the $e_i$ involves only $e_1$, $\ldots e_{n-1}$ and is of degree $>0$. Therefore, every such monomial evaluated in $e_1$, $\ldots e_n$ give $0$, and so $P(x_1, \ldots, x_n)= 0$.

Answer (score 0):

For $n$, $a$ integers, $n>0$ the map

$$ k\!\!\!\!\mod n \mapsto a k \!\!\!\!\mod n$$
maps $\mathbb{Z}/n $ onto $\gcd (a,n)\cdot \mathbb{Z}/n\simeq \mathbb{Z}/(n/d)$ with fibres of cardinality $\gcd (a,n)=\colon d$. Therefore we have

$$S_a = \gcd (a,n)\cdot S'_1$$

where the sum $S'$ is the sum of the roots of the equation $X^{\frac{n}{d}}-1$, and this from Viete's equalities is $0$ is $d < n$, and $n$ if $d= n$.